gam()'s AIC much better than lm()'s AIC but the fitted line looks just fine?
I am fitting a linear regression and a generalized additive model for a variable y on a variable x.
x <- c(-0.753828171223374, -0.702421304886483, -0.525922071232559, 
-0.499368711904991, -0.494072179316426, -0.408973650360027, -0.402501994567026, 
-0.393058036248241, -0.392954967411319, -0.37951900393503, -0.358729140897481, 
-0.354401065704234, -0.351959888288872, -0.347631549547629, -0.336772700038351, 
-0.331820704037377, -0.320011921562785, -0.276909999285465, -0.266889198383766, 
-0.246941396419386, -0.244771638528946, -0.241667325754278, -0.239862531253802, 
-0.239185579638141, -0.217923773010234, -0.210894666779951, -0.202232589003839, 
-0.201577138947226, -0.189989677738178, -0.170028487080187, -0.169948604137679, 
-0.1681371544387, -0.162139417875546, -0.161745070325861, -0.156213109801138, 
-0.15493800075576, -0.148175380031207, -0.144384450725271, -0.133817109830678, 
-0.129777063600703, -0.1292091226338, -0.125152129666695, -0.118735714834316, 
-0.111943843076971, -0.111034497847886, -0.108324755495965, -0.102007561490731, 
-0.0995348705098378, -0.0975507338173421, -0.0967166195464575, 
-0.0960915620786561, -0.0952305897001864, -0.0918858930340224, 
-0.0872704628484125, -0.0819739302598472, -0.0814370678277665, 
-0.0799673929994122, -0.0746482691048439, -0.0731783844597705, 
-0.0687800157013639, -0.0676255991392163, -0.0668859451913174, 
-0.0618632353474433, -0.0608624334403485, -0.0581546269777062, 
-0.0577473682846916, -0.0550799073614832, -0.0543448633682753, 
-0.0492788317611553, -0.0492650199318009, -0.0346679553082839, 
-0.0328026677594039, -0.0321049879170871, -0.028895963635458, 
-0.0288372399469618, -0.0253752723256008, -0.024884201232001, 
-0.0219161736261679, -0.0218622913269024, -0.0165961745229844, 
-0.0151535738668643, -0.0141964280835251, -0.011901707954635, 
-0.010745658280727, -0.00886098925906957, -0.00827629311172754, 
-0.00717935456553159, -0.00585307757528461, -0.00432924344834757, 
-0.00417077611570543, -0.00161521775514871, 0.00116096458829085, 
0.00124274561578785, 0.00405340513681626, 0.00650198240222148, 
0.00781442918023, 0.0098245558005554, 0.00983836762990968, 0.011862327044839, 
0.0127208310401385)

y <- c(1.33172309918366, 1.29234488688529, 1.16009460627154, 1.14061600316299, 
1.13674431384791, 1.07517693128238, 1.07054498210084, 1.0637986685122, 
1.06372512642011, 1.05415410073461, 1.03940703453916, 1.03634657979141, 
1.03462185255625, 1.03156643151142, 1.02391581222465, 1.02043391177591, 
1.01214868032632, 0.982124153875601, 0.975193052917491, 0.961451930427496, 
0.959961824357313, 0.957831458685827, 0.95659374398089, 0.95612965570678, 
0.941598163079392, 0.93681323423608, 0.930929874764137, 0.93048528155551, 
0.922639340714301, 0.909185402331939, 0.90913171917749, 0.907914724026396, 
0.903889893760358, 0.903625514712141, 0.899920043104334, 0.899066804962311, 
0.894547051519526, 0.892017427898862, 0.884981322129501, 0.882297290821055, 
0.881920241135721, 0.87922875625951, 0.87497883311667, 0.870489394143986, 
0.869889033006586, 0.868101033970136, 0.863938556198595, 0.862311509762884, 
0.861006848524175, 0.860458623020468, 0.860047895434157, 0.859482279700875, 
0.85728643866709, 0.854260154984101, 0.850792740909708, 0.850441606324925, 
0.849480674019862, 0.846006590839454, 0.84504760832673, 0.842180730040725, 
0.841428948726826, 0.840947417162972, 0.837680564868377, 0.837030262264296, 
0.835271839520591, 0.835007503750959, 0.833277025872084, 0.832800441010304, 
0.829518862141146, 0.829509922816415, 0.820085081102358, 0.818884005318737, 
0.818434954371892, 0.816370859116157, 0.816333107697294, 0.814108838254362, 
0.813793540093344, 0.811888986875533, 0.811854428685852, 0.808479950271578, 
0.807556590298442, 0.806944201958174, 0.805476832045287, 0.804738022520511, 
0.803534187360152, 0.803160868437218, 0.802460691345483, 0.801614476292256, 
0.800642684272931, 0.800541654170489, 0.798913124672818, 0.797145614744474, 
0.797093572760474, 0.795305875213213, 0.793749883850904, 0.792916406337899, 
0.791640594006648, 0.79163183080376, 0.790348139656543, 0.78980390704364
)

library(mgcv)


model_linear <- lm(y ~ x)

AIC(model_linear)

fit <- Vectorize(function(x) as.numeric(coef(model_linear)[1] + coef(model_linear)[2]*x))
plot(x,y)
curve(fit, -1,0.2, n = 1000, lwd =2, col = "red", add =TRUE)


model_gam <- gam(y ~ s(x), method = "ML")
AIC(model_gam)

I use the command AIC() to calculate the AIC of both models, as shown in the reproducible code provided. The AIC for the linear model is -859.0262 while the AIC for the gam is -2006.344, yet, the linear model looks just fine.
How come the gam model is massively better without providing a much better fit and having more parameters?

Please tell us how you compute the AICs.  (That detail would be buried in the innards of lm, glm, and AIC.)  If you use different functions to do that, be aware that they might use different conventions for the log likelihood--that, after all, is defined only up to an arbitrary additive constant--so there's no reason to suppose one function's AIC could be compared to another function's AIC even if both functions purported to do exactly the same analysis!

@whuber I use the command AIC() as shown in the reproducible code provided. AIC(model_linear) and AIC(model_gam).

Try running a summary on the two models.  You will observe that the GAM has, almost, a perfect fit - the residual variance is roughly $10^{-10}$ - while the residual variance for the linear model is only $10^{-5}$.  So, with a residual variance that's about 1/100,000 as large, the GAM model is providing a much better fit.  If the smallness of the residuals, in an absolute sense, bothers you, just multiply y by 100,000 and then do the comparison.

@jbowman Thank you. I could accept that as an answer. I was thinking that parsimony would favor the linear model, but that does not seem to be the case.

I'll write it up more comprehensively soon, addressing your last point.  Thanks!

@jbowman Can you add the comment so I can accept it and then you make any additions you want?

Try running a summary on the two models. You will observe that the GAM has almost a perfect fit - the residual variance is roughly $10^{−10}$, while the residual variance for the linear model is only $10^{−5}$, albeit both are considerably smaller than the variance of y (roughly $10^{-2}$).
So, with a residual variance that's about 1/100,000 as large, the GAM model is providing a much better fit. If the smallness of the residuals, in an absolute sense, bothers you, multiply y by 100,000 and then make the comparison.
